# creating case class in scala from csv file

Tags: scala

I have a input `csv` file delimited with | which has 50 records.
What is the best way to create `case class` from these records?

One basic way is to read the `csv` file line by line and split based on | and pass all 50 records to instantiate a `case class` like

```
fields = line.split("|")

TransactionRecord(fields[0],fields[1],fields[2],......fields[50])
```

But this is very basic and would need change if schema changes

Any effective way to instantiate the `case class` like using some config to generalize?

Comment: I do not understand well what is your target. You want to read all records from `csv` file and create a one `class` with all data? Another way is to create a `case class` with `List` and pass all records as list.

Comment: This library will solve your problem: https://github.com/zamblauskas/scala-csv-parser

Comment: @allocer - can you elaborate with an example pls?

Comment: @AllenHan - i could not add them as dependencies in build.sbt as it is giving 404 ( not found).. i checked it does not exists.. any other suggestion?

Comment: @sinha It worked for me. Use scalaVersion 2.12.1 with version 0.11.6. Sometimes you need to downgrade or upgrade the scalaVersion in your project to get these dependencies to load.

Comment: @AllenHan - Thanks a lot for your advice... My project uses scala 2.11.8. Any other way? it will be a discussion to migrate to scala 2.12.1

Comment: moreover, i see that the scala 2.12.1 support only 2.4 spark . my spark is 2.2.0 only

Comment: You can create a project with the dependency just so you can download it. Then try loading the jar into your project manually by copying from the .ivy2 folder. It's worth a try.

Comment: You can also try downgrading the version of a library to an older version. There's probably going to be a version that works with 2.11.8. What we did at our company is that we downloaded the dependency, customized it, and uploaded it to our own private repo.